# Spring security @PreFilter & @PostFilter for reactive methods

Tags: spring-security, project-reactor, spring-security-acl

Is there an example of using @PostFilter ACL's in spring-security on a domain object say X , which is reactive ? For example, the method signature would be

> `public Flux<X> repositoryMethod()`.

I did implement my own `PermissionEvaluator` which I have configured on to `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` , but on applying the @PostFilter on repositoryMethod,I encounter the exception

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter target must be a collection, array, map or stream type, but was Mono.flatMapMany ⇢ at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAdviceReactiveMethodInterceptor.invoke(PrePostAdviceReactiveMethodInterceptor.java:125)`,which clearly tells me that this is not expected.So I'm stranded and would appreciate some help.

Comment: I don't see a reactive version of PermissionEvaluator or for that matter DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.Am I missing something ?